# Best way to create animations in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

In my game I need to create 2 kind of 2D animation:

- Static 2D animations: this's like a short video and play it in a part of game screen
- Dynamic 2D animations: this's have some data returned from server(number, text) and include it to the animations.

Do you know what is the best way to do above things?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I haven't tried yet, but in cocos2d I have to make animations by a tons of code(transform, scale,...) and waste time

Comment: I suggest trying then coming back once you've had a stab at it, then we can help.

Comment: @KiemDuong Unity or cocos2d? If Unity, how do you get your models into Unity and are they rigged? Which version of Unity3D 3.x or 4.x?

Comment: I need to make Sprite 2D animation in Unity 4.0

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to animate 2D content in Unity3D I can think of:

- manually via code and UV scale & offset
- using a shader editor like [Strumpy Shader](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/56180-Strumpy-Shader-Editor-Now-Open-Source)
- using an add-on like [ex2d](http://www.ex-dev.com/ex2d/)

I would recommend you search the assets store in the Unity3D Editor and see what frameworks/add-ons are out there :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also create animations of arbitrary complexity in Maya, Max or any program that exports animated FBX files and import them into unity as data